# I can't make sense of minified javascript " let {styles:t={}} = e "

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, minify

I can't make sense of the following javascript code. This is taken from "minified" javascript of a react application.

```
var foo=e=>{
            let {styles:t={}}   =   e,
                n               =  function(e,t){
                                    ...
                                    return n}
                                    (e,["styles"]);
            
            ...        
            return createElement("svg" ...)
           };
```

Someone generated the same "code"
https://github.com/boopathi/react-svg-loader/issues/201 and complains the generated arrow function is not supported by IE11. This seems to be fixed by including babel-loader in the compilation process.

I don't care about IE, so let's continue with the arrow function

```
var foo=e=>{
            ...        
            ...        
            ...        
            return createElement("svg" ...)
           };
```

Ok foo is an arrow function

```
                n               =  function(e,t){
                                    ...
                                    return n}
                                    (e,["styles"]);
```

set the value of n as the result of calling an inline function to which we pass e and ["styles"] as args.

```
            let ...             =  ... ,
                n               =  ...
```

Ok we set the values of two vars.
Let's continue.

```
let {styles:t={}}   =   e,
```

I thought

```
{styles:t={}}
```

will evaluate to

```
{styles:true}
```

but as t={} evaluates as Object then

```
{styles:t={}} = Object { styles: {} }
```

Then we got our final instruction that makes no sense to me:

```
let {styles:t={}}   =   e
```

Any idea?

Comment: It's a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with renaming and a default value, `t = e.styles || {}`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found the following link https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment more enlightening than the plain MDN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by jonrsharpe It's a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with renaming and a default value, t = e.styles || {}

Many Thanks to him. I found the following link https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment more enlightening than the plain MDN